# Not able to create a new collection-type in Strapi Dashboard

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, strapi

I had just created a STRAPI project using , find docs [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start.html#_1-install-strapi-and-create-a-new-project)

```
npx create-strapi-app@latest my-shop1
```

And then sign up to the admin portal. After signing up, I reached `dashboard>>content-Type Builder` . Then as soon as I click on `create new collection type`, the create collection modal is not showing up. Even clicking many times does not help me. Also, I checked whether my mode is development or not, but it is `development`  which is correct.

[image: err2]

Also, I am unable to edit the default `User` collection. On Clicking User above I am getting this in the URL

```
http://localhost:1337/admin/plugins/content-type-builder/content-types/plugin::users-permissions.user
```

[image: err3]

I want to know why I am not able to create any collection? Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. Use yarn develop instead of npm start. In my case this solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: in case you are using npm try => npm run develop

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the "start" script so you cannot do it whit this.
Please run it with the "npm run develop" command or you can use yarn as well instead of npm.

Answer (score 0):

`User` collection cannot be edited by default. You only can to add new fields.

For the other problems, remove the folder '`node_modules`', after run `npm install`, in CLI, in root directory, and then `npm run develop`.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same issue with Strapi. This is due to your brower.
Try again with Chrome it will work.

Comment: I already worked with chrome. Do I need to change browser or try with chrome again,???